# Subaru Forester power window stuck

Tags: subaru, forester

My Subaru Forester 2014, has its driver side power window stuck while closed. It was up all winter and now its not responding.

Does OBD tell if the motor had gone bad, or something else ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a test probe? If so, check that the buttons are sending a current to the motor's relays. If you've left it in one position, it might be a good idea to use a silicon spray into all the grooves. If this doesn't work, pull out the door cards and directly supply the motor with 12DCV from either the battery or a test probe (preferably.)

If it's stuck after testing that, you may need a new motor. Good luck!

Comment: As a further note, the OBD2 ports are used for more major components (Ignition, EGR, ABS, Airbags, etc) and wouldn't display anything for the window motors. They require you to physically test them, whereas things like your airbags or your ABS are things that are dangerous to check yourself, so have built-in sensors that tell you. Things that are either dangerous, time-consuming or not serviceable almost always have sensors to let you know when something's not happy. Things like window motors and washer jets and other trivial things like that, they will tell you they don't work by not working.